# SiteMapPortalProvider

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I'm trying to build a custom navigation entity off the existing SiteMapPortalProvider exposed through SharePoint 2010, however, I cannot seem to find the settings to replicate a particular sub-site's navigational settings.

Take the following into account:

-> Sub Site -> Current Navigation

1. About Us
2. Contact Us
3. Should Be Hidden (Hidden)
4. Should Be Hidden (Hidden)
5. Corporate Info

I retrieve the current SiteMapPortalProvider from SharePoint and pass the following attributes:

- IncludeAuthoredLinks = true
- IncludeHeadings = true
- IncludePages = PerWeb
- IncludeSubSites = PerWeb
- NavigationType = Combined

As this replicated the navigational settings for the sub-site I'm trying to simulate.

I then do subsequent calls to the SiteMapPortalProvider to get the items, as listed above, and pass the following parameters through:

- NodeTypes.All,
- NodeTypes.All,
- OrderingMethod.Manual
- AutomaticSortingMethod.CreatedDate

However, the above code returns the (Hidden) items to be visible to the user.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Hi Steve, to a degree yes.

Comment: Ok, good. Did my answer help you or not?  If so, please accept my answer, if not, please post the appropriate answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661621.aspx

the second nodetypes parameter is what type of hidden nodes should be included (includedHiddenTypes).  So shouldn't the second parameter where you have NodeTypes.All be NodeTypes.None?